# If not applicable, ignore JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I have this function that changes the element of some markup that I don't have control over. It has been working great, but on some pages - there is no element of that name. My JS is all compiled to one file - and so on the pages with no match, I get an `error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attributes' of undefined`

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.changeElementType = function(newType) {

        // create object to store attributes
        var attrs = {};

        // save out the values to that object
        $.each(this[0].attributes, function(idx, attr) {
            attrs[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
        });

        // replace the element itself - and put the original values back
        this.replaceWith(function() {
            return $("<" + newType + "/>", attrs).append($(this).contents());
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

(for example, this should be a list and not just tons of divs)
`$('.list-view').changeElementType('ul');`

So my instinct is to put an `if` statement or something so that if no match is there - it just doesn't get in the way. - But I'm not really sure on what direction to take.

I used to use function expressions for almost everything, so I think that's why I've never really needed to deal with this.

Comment: Just `return` if `this.length === 0`.

Comment: Why did someone downvote this?

Comment: I'm guessing, but probably because it's trivial to solve with bog-standard application of minimal thought.

Comment: @Pointy - Thanks. Makes sense. If you put that in an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you can just return if there is no match. This would happen if `this.length` is `0`. So for instance you could change your code to the following:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.changeElementType = function(newType) {

        // If there is no match, return
        if (this.length === 0) return;

        // create object to store attributes
        var attrs = {};

        // save out the values to that object
        $.each(this[0].attributes, function(idx, attr) {
            attrs[attr.nodeName] = attr.nodeValue;
        });

        // replace the element itself - and put the original values back
        this.replaceWith(function() {
            return $("<" + newType + "/>", attrs).append($(this).contents());
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: @sheriffderek Curly braces group together multiple lines of code into a block. If you only have one line of code, the braces are optional on most control structures (though people tend to be opinionated on whether you should still use them for readability).